# Squares of adjunctions / Galois correspondences

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

$
\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}
\newcommand{\PS}{\mathcal P}
\newcommand{\Idl}{\operatorname{Idl}}
$

There are many situations where one encounters a square of things which are related by pairs of adjoint functors:

[image: Square of functors]

where $f\dashv g$ means that $f$ is left adjoint to $g$.

Example: $f\colon R\to S$ is a morphism of rings, $X=\PS R$ and $Y=\PS S$ are the powersets of $R$ and $S$, and $A=\Idl(R)$ and $B=\Idl(B)$ are the lattices of ideals of $R$ and $S$; the adjunctions are "ideal generated by a powerset $\dashv$ ideal viewed as subset", "extension of ideal $\dashv$ contraction of ideal, and two instances of "direct image of subset $\dashv$ inverse image of subset".

Alternatively, one of the adjunctions may be a Galois correspondence instead; for example, a ring map $f\colon R\to S$ induces adjunctions between $\mathcal P\Spec(R)$ and $\mathcal P\Spec(S)$, as well as between the lattices of ideals of $R$ and $S$; but $\mathcal P(\Spec(S))$ and $\Idl(S)$ are related by a Galois correspondence ($I$ and $V$) rather than an adjunction.

What is the succinct categorical way to describe such squares (of either type)? I imagine the answer is something to do with double categories...  On a more practical level: I have several examples of such "compatible squares of adjoints/correspondences", such as those listed above, and am in search of a formal definition of "compatible square".

1. Given a quadruplet of adjunctions, what conditions should I demand for them to be "compatible"?
2. What equalities (or just natural transformations) can I infer from such a square?

For the most part I only care about the case of posets, but of course a general categorical answer would be most satisfying.

Comment: Nice question. Exercise 4.2.iv in Emily Riehl's *Category theory in context* ( http://www.math.harvard.edu/~eriehl/161/context.pdf ) defines morphisms of adjunctions. An adjoint pair of such morphisms would look like your diagram. I'm wondering if the notion is symmetric -- i.e., whether an adjoint pair of morphisms of adjunctions remains an adjoint pair of morphisms of adjunctions if we switch the roles of the morphisms with that of the adjunctions. That would be a logical thing to do.

Comment: I would suggest the *bicategory of profunctors* as a pair of adjoint functors $F\dashv G$ determines one profunctor $F_*\cong G^*$.